# How can I disable C Lang File Permission notification everytime I debug a program

Tags: mac, filesystems, c

I am trying to debug a simple c program and everytime I run the debug VS Code gives me this notification saying the program I am running is trying to get access to Desktop (surely it means the path where C program resides).

I was thinking of getting rid of this notification. Does anyone have any quick fix?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Move your work folders (the ones containing your source files) away from Desktop, e.g. into `%HOME%`.